# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace

Tags: scala, apache-spark, playframework-2.6, metaspace

I am facing a problem of metaSpace in my project.

I am using Scala IDE in which Spark 2.3.1, Play framework 2.6, Scala 2.11

While running `sbt run`, I get a meta-space error.

Also, I had tried to run `sbt clean`.

But it gives the same error:

[image: error]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To be able to help you, we need as well code

Answer (score 0):

Use Spark 2.4.0 and greater with Scala version 2.11.11 this will help fix those minor bugs.

build.sbt

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.11"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" %% "jackson-module-scala" % "2.9.8",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-repl" % "2.4.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
)
```

Then add jackson-module-scala will help you override the deprecated version on the library if ever there is error on jackson version..  Let me know if there still errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.jvmopts` file in the root folder of your project, and write inside the file the following:

```
-Xms1g
-Xmx4g
```

That will set the maximum memory allocation pool to 4 Gigabyte and the initial memory allocation pool to 1 Gigabyte.